# Extracting static fields from Eclipse project using Rascal

Tags: java, eclipse, rascal

I am using Rascal to analyze an Eclipse project and I was wondering if it is possible to detect whether a certain field is declared as `static`, like `static int x;`.

I have created an M3 model for my project and using `fields(model)` I can obtain all the fields that are present within my project.

I would like to be able to extract any `static` fields from this set (without having to check the original code myself).

Is this possible within Rascal and if so, how can I extract them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`modifiers`](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/analysis/m3/Core/modifiers/modifiers.html) relation.

Inside Rascal you can find the definition of `Modifier` in `rascal > lang > java > m3 > AST.rsc` (also included in the tutor at: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/AST/Declaration/Declaration.html )